# SQL Server : new and old value from history table in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

have a history table some thing like

```
id  user    vendor      createdtime 
1   sree    a           12/29/2014 23:12:21
1   sree    a           12/29/2014 23:13:21
1   sree    b           12/29/2014 23:14:21
1   jack    a           12/29/2014 23:14:21
1   jack    a           12/29/2014 23:11:21
1   sree    a           12/29/2014 23:11:21
```

and need result something like

```
id      user        old vendor      new vendor      createdtime
1       sree                        a               12/29/2014 23:12:21
1       sree        a               a               12/29/2014 23:13:21
1       sree        a               b               12/29/2014 23:14:21
1       jack        b               a               12/29/2014 23:14:21
1       jack        a               a               12/29/2014 23:11:21
1       sree        a               a               12/29/2014 23:11:21
```

Comment: That's totally unreadable. Please edit your question, perhaps including a SQL Fiddle demo.

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?

Comment: I think he wants to join to the previous version based on the id and createdtime?

Comment: Unless you have some other column to order by besides the `createdtime` it is impossible to accomplish what you ask as you have duplicate values for `createdtime`which makes it impossible to order by in a stable manner.

Comment: Thanks @CodeByMoonlight for editing actually i was unable to do that. and my question is correct am getting duplicate 'createdtime' also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use the `lag()` function:

```
select h.*, lag(vendor) over (partition by user order by createdtime) as prev_vendor
from history h;
```

In earlier versions, you can do this with a subquery.  However, `outer apply` is more powerful:

```
select h.*, hprev.vendor as prev_vendor
from history h outer apply
     (select top 1 h2.*
      from history h2
      where h2.vendor = h.vendor
      order by createdtime
     ) hprev;
```

This allows you to pull more columns out from the previous record -- for instance, not just the vendor name but also the `createdtime`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select h.id as id , h.[user] as [user],
(select top 1 h2.vendor 
         from History h2 
         where h2.[user] = h.[user] and h2.createdtime < h.createdtime
         order by h2.createdtime desc ) as [old vendor],
     h.vendor as [new vendor]

     from History h 
     order by h.createdtime
```